# "Error loading operating system"

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot

when i try to load windows I get

`error loading operating system`

if i load a usb rescue disk (hirens boot tools) I can use an option on the menu which says

```
Boot windows (ntldr)
```

to jump start the botting process and windows will load. I dont want to keep doing this. The boot flag is set to on when i look at some other tools from the usb rescue disk.

In the rescue disk there is also an option to "fix ntldr missing error", this doesnt work.

Anyone got any suggestionso

Comment: Should be on SuperUser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first things I would try is running a [`fixmbr`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/bootcons_fixmbr.mspx?mfr=true). Since the boot disk is getting you into the OS, it seems that the system is having a hard time passing control to the kernel from boot. The system can definitely see your hard disk though.

Comment: This is what I was going to recommend. Most likely the Master Boot Record was corrupted at some point and is no longer pointing to the correct OS partition

Answer (score 1):

did you install Windows 7 beforehand? If so, you might have a boot partition, check if that is working correctly.

Also, just to rule out any error possibilities, check BIOS for boot order.

Since you have a rescue disc, first thing you should do, is a backup. Then you might consider a reinstall, just to spare you some hair pulling...

Comment: +1 for mentioning BIOS. This is a common error if you are using more than one hdd. I personally experienced this recently. I don´t know why but my BIOS had set the second disc as bootdis. Ergo: error loading operating system ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Windows Vista/7, boot to the Windows disc, bypass the Repair Your Computer screen, open a command prompt and type `bootrec /fixmbr`.

Edit: I know John just mentioned this but `bootrec` is required in Vista/7.

Answer (score 0):

Whoa, the first step should be to back up the boot sector/record so you can put it back.  Then you have the freedom to experiment with the live ones, knowing you have an undo.  It may be too late for that.  But Windows disk tools have a way of single-mindedly trashing things to accomplish a single goal and sometimes that doesn't work so you're left with nothing.

I got here because I didn't remember where (BIOS or Grub) the "error loading operating system" message originates from.  I don't actively use Windows but it's on there, along with OpenBSD and most recently Linux.  Is there a primary partition that's flagged bootable?  OK, that would be my first guess, then look at replacing the MBR.  But hopefully after you've got some backup.  The old Norton Disk Editor could do that, or from Linux/Unix, use dd.  Somewhere in there are things like sector numbers on the drive where partitions start (partition table probably), and you can't just replace that with a vanilla one, those numbers have to be right for your drive and partitions.